# Proof of Riesz's representation theorem in Stein's Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, hilbert-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

I'm having some trouble regarding a step in the proof as it appears in Stein's Real Analysis.
[image]

How is that the construction of $u$ guarantees that $u \in S$?. I obviously tried seeing that $l(u) = 0$ but ended nowhere.

Comment: Use the fact $\ell$ is linear along with $\ell(f),\ell(h) \in \mathbb{C}$ to evaluate $\ell(u)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\ell (f)$ and $\ell (h)$ are scalars. So linearity gives $\ell(u)=\ell (f)\ell (h)-\ell (h)\ell (f)=0$.